# How to list the variables or attribute inside a function of a class?

Tags: python

**Sample code:**

```
class hello:
    cls_var_name='Hello_Class'
    def setdata(self, value):
        self.data=value
        fun1_var_name='Setdata_Function'
    def showdata(self):
        fun2_var_name='Showdata_Function'
        print(self.data)
```

So, With the help of the `dir()` function, we can list all the attribute of a class. but how to list out variables/attributes inside the function of a class.

**Demo:**

```
>>> dir(hello)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'cls_var_name', 'setdata', 'showdata']
>>>
>>> dir(hello.setdata)
['__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__func__', '__get__', 
'__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'im_class', 'im_func', 'im_self']
>>>
>>> dir(hello.showdata)
['__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__func__', '__get__',
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
 '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'im_class', 'im_func', 'im_self']
```

In the above output you can seen the list of attribute of a class in `dir(hello)` result:
`'cls_var_name', 'setdata', 'showdata'`

But for `dir(hello.setdata)` and `dir(hello.showdata)` result it list out all the related attribute but not a `fun1_var_name` and `fun2_var_name` variable, why?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Why do we have the dir() function then? For that we can see attributes/variables and functions inside a class with dir() help, So in the same way just wanted to know about the list of variables inside a function, just for curiosity.

Comment: @Rajesh Since object attributes are actually a thing that persists for as long as the obhect, getting their names via `dir` allows to access them. No such thing is possible for function variables, since they only exist for less than a short moment while the function executes.

Comment: "but not a fun1_var_name and fun2_var_name variable, why?" Because they **aren't** attributes, and *only exist while the function is running*.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is because the `dir` function displays a list of properties and attributes that are bound to an object. `fun_var_name` is not an attribute of the `setdata` method, it is a variable that lives within the scope of the method body and discarded as soon as it exits.

So when you call `dir(hello.showdata)` unless the call is made inside the `showdata` method, `func2_var_name` doesn't exist, however even if it was, the variable still would not appear using the `dir` function because it is not bound to the callable method object.  (A "callable method object" is simply another term for a method, but it emphasizes the fact that methods, like pretty much everything in python, are also objects.)

If what you desire is the means of accessing a list of variable names you can use the `vars()` function, but it will only show variables that have already been defined and are within the current scope.  like this:

```
class hello:
    cls_var_name='Hello_Class'

    def setdata(self, value):
        self.data=value
        fun1_var_name='Setdata_Function'
        print(vars())

    def showdata(self):
        fun2_var_name='Showdata_Function'
        print(self.data)
        print(vars())
```

Getting the variable names from outside of the method body isn't possible because those variables don't exist.

A case could be made for using the `inspect` module and getting the actual source code, but I don't think that is what you had in mind.

Comment: Hey @alexpdev! Could you please elaborate on the line "is not bound to the callable method object". Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much @alexpdev! Also, could you please show the usage of `vars` inside `showdata`. If I got you right (which I'm pretty sure I didn't), printing `vars(hello.showdata)` inside `showdata` should display `fun2_var_name`, right?

Comment: Hi @alexpdev, Thanks for the answer.
Is there any way to see the list of variables of functions without calling/executing it?

Comment: @Rajesh The only thing I can think of is you can get the actual source code for a function or method using  `inspect.getsource()`

Comment: @alexpdev, I was just curious to know, Is there any way to find it. And the possible reason could be while debugging or writing a code and to oversee any static attribute/variable values or names.